# Cannot Update State in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using React with ES2015. I have this in my state:

```
this.state = { info: {
            merchandise: {
              label: '',
              visible: false
            },
            hotels: {
              label: '',
              visible: false
            }
    }
}
```

I'm try to update state with this code:

```
this.setState({info.merchandise.label: "New Label"})
```

but I get an error whereas I can log the value of `this.state.info.merchandise.label` without any issues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you'll have to actually set the value of `this.state.info` to `{merchandise: {label: "New Label", visible: false}, hotels: {label: '', visible: false}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can only use `setState()` on a *direct* property of `this.state`.

What you could do in this situation is

1. Make a shallow copy of `state` property you want to work with
2. Change the property you want changed in the copy.
3. The copy now has the updated properties you wanted. So assign it back to `this.state`

Like so:

```
let temp = Object.assign({}, this.state.info);
temp.merchandise.label = "New Label";
this.setState(info: temp);
```

Comment: Sure I will, thanks. I would like to add that some other solutions provided by others worked too but I found this one to be the easiest. Thanks to all you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following,

```
let newState = this.state;
newState.info.merchandise.label = "New Label";
this.setState(newState);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [React's setState doc](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> Performs a shallow merge of nextState into current state

This means you should provide a valid `nextState` object as argument to the method. `{info.merchandise.label: "New Label"}` is not syntactically correct, that's why you get an error.

> Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

This simply means that if you want to change some property inside the state object, you should not mutate it directly, but replace it with a new object containing the modification instead.

In your case, the state object contains several nested objects. If you want to modify a "leaf" object's property, you'll also have to provide new objects for every containing object up the tree (because each of them have a property that changes in the process). Using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create new objects, you could write:

```
// new "leaf" object:
const newMerchandise = Object.assign({}, this.state.info.merchandise,
    {label: "New Label"});

// new "parent" object:
const newInfo = Object.assign({}, this.state.info,
    {merchandise: newMerchandise});

// new state ("parent") object:
const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state,
    {info: newInfo});

// eventually:
this.setState(newState);
```

By the way, you'll notice that it's easier to handle the state object when its structure tends to be "flat" rather than "deeply nested".